# Conditionally fire only one of two bound mouseOver events in jQuery / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary, imagemap, qtip

I have a U.S. map that uses the [jQuery Maphilight](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/) plug-in (**see [this Maphilight demo](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_usa.html)**). My code follows:

```
$('.map').maphilight();
```

I have combined it with the jQuery [qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/) plug-in. I have the qTip tool tips set to show when the user hovers over each `<area>` on the map. My code follows:

```
$('area').each(function() {
    $(this).qtip({
        content: $(this).attr('data'),
    });
});
```

So the 'highlighting' and the 'tool tip' both occur when the user moves over each `<area>`.

I also have a legend. Using the Maphilight demo above, the legend would have pink, purple, green, and yellow. I want to move over the, e.g., yellow legend key and highlight all of the yellow fields.

To do this, I set a `class` attribute on each state `<area>` to its actual color. On each legend-color `<area>` I set a `class="color"` and `myColor` equal to actual color. I have the following JavaScript, which as per the [Maphilight documentation](http://davidlynch.org/js/maphilight/docs/demo_features.html), simulates a `mouseOver` on each `<area>` to activate the highlighting.

```
<area class="color" myColor="yellow">
$('.color').mouseover(function() {
    $('.' + $(this).attr('myColor')).mouseover();
});

$('.color').mouseout(function(e) {
    $('.' + $(this).attr(myColor)).mouseout();
});
```

However, as you can imagine, *this also brings up the tool tip for every single state of that color*. How can I activate only one `mouseOver` event when two are bound?

This must be a common jQuery problem that is certainly outside the bounds of this particular scenerio, but I am unsure how to search for it. Is there typically a method in each jQuery plug-in that allows you to simulate the effect on one particular selection (i.e., `$('area#some_id')`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like maphilight is namespacing its events.  So, you should be able to do this:

```
$('.' + $(this).attr(myColor)).trigger("mouseover.maphilight");
```

EDIT: For info on namespaced events: http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events